# JavaFX, material icon visible in scenebuilder preview but not visible when i run the program

Tags: javafx, icons, scenebuilder

I am trying to build a java FX app with Idea and scene builder, I used a png file from Google material design Icon and put it into an asset folder in my project, then reference it in scene builder in a imageview as a button. it is visible when I preview it in the scene builder but invisible when I try to run the program, anyone knows what might have caused this?

Comment: [Eden has a resource guide](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/) I advise you to study.